# how I removed whole non ascii string extracted from barcode extracted using pypdf2 in python? mantion that not the text below barcode

Tags: python, data-analysis, text-extraction

I have convert  pdf to text using pyPDF2 package in python and I  want to extract specific word from this text but it cause error when I pass the sentences to code because of  there pypdf2 package convert barcode in following manner.
please help me to solve this error.
I have this type of text file named "acc-53.txt":

### "-aUUID:F9F537ED-3066-4E99-B6D1-112D5C4551F0'RO76TCGA-OR-Acm-91A-PRIII 11111 IIIIHIIIIIIII1111111111111IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII1111IIIedIII 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111III 111111111111 IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII I IIII I IIIIIII III IIII 11111111 I IIIC'' 1e.' i'+6 Jed&rf0-7q.b^JcronnL k4ored6m aeeAly,,ph/e.-^^ 1 a ^c^rr/e t, ,tzt av 1.1Procedure:L nephrectomy, preirenal and paraaortal LNGross description: 11 x 10.5 x 9cm, 497gDiagnosis:adrenocortical carcinoma, small LN in the specimen are free of tumorReference Pathology:Diagnosis:adrenocortical carcinoma, K167 5-10%, high grade 5 per 10 hpfWeiss score: 2Hough score: 1.69Van Slooten score: 5.7lun.o, Site riscrNpnney`._...--_I I IAAr I-re.y-'r i:u h7a!ignan^y Iij^oSYlun!IS; ncnlunou:,'Ji^'r'J r''^nlnEi'.Patient # from Tissue Source SiteDate of reportDate of Surgery/specimen collectionSite (confirmed to be adrenal) with laterality indicatedLeftTumor size(s)11x10.5x9cmHistologic diagnosisACCLymph Node Status0/4PathologicinformationT2 NOWeiss score2, but K167 5-10% and Dx of ACC, by reference pathologist"

I have already tried following patterns to remove this lines:

1. `regex = re.findall('\w+ k774$ ',text)`
2. `text.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin')`
3. `regex = '\u00?'`
4. from unidecode import unidecode
   def remove_non_ascii(text):
           return unidecode(unicode(text, encoding = "utf-8"))
5. `regex = re.findall('\III IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII IIIIIN IIIIIIIIIIIIIII I I IH I!IIII I IIIIIII I IIIIIIII II !IIIIIIIIIIIIIli, l I I !III IIIIII IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII ',sentences)`
6. re.sub('\u00E2||\u20AC', '', sentences)

---

```
from unidecode import unidecode

text = pdf_file.read()
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)

print(sentences)

def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return unidecode(unicode(text, encoding = "utf-8"))

print(regex)

def findInfo():
    uuId = re.findall('\w{8}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{4}\-\w{12}',sentences)   
    Gender= re.findall('female|Female|male|Male$',sentences)   
    tSize = re.findall( r'\d+?\.?\d+?\s?x?\s?\d+?\.?\d+?\s?x?\s?\d+?\.? 
    \d+mm|cm$',sentences)  

    Diag = re.findall(r'(DIAGNOSIS|Diagnosis):(.*?),',sentences)
    side = re.findall(r'(LEFT SIDE):(.*?),', sentences)

    return uuId,Gender,tSize, Diag , side
```

---

barcode decoded string would be removed from the text for further processing.

Comment: what if using `.replace("|","")` ?

Comment: it also not working..

Comment: This seems like a regex problem. I find this website really useful https://regexr.com/. You can copy paste your text and your regex, and it will highlight the regions. I find it much easier to set up my regex there

Comment: i have tried this site its realy good, but I haven't found any useful regex for this special characters i,e,"III 11111 IIIIHIIIIIIII1111111111111IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII1111IIIedIII 1111111111111111" .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with Strings, you can simply use the .replace() function to remove special characters. Like so:

```
line.replace('|', '')
```

Another example:

```
someline = 'red blue green'
print(someline.replace('blue', ''))
```

Which prints: "red green"

Comment: the OP said, `.replace()` function doesn't work. Please check all comments first before answering

Comment: Pretty difficult when OP post while im typing my answer but yes, will be careful.